# Подсчет суммы целых чисел в строке

Tags: c#

Есть метод:

```
static int SumNumbersInLine(string line)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int i = 0;
            string number = "";
            while (i < line.Length)
            {
                if (line[i] == '-' && i != line.Length - 1 && Char.IsDigit(line[i + 1]))
                {
                    number += line[i];
                    i++;
                }
                if (Char.IsDigit(line[i]))
                {
                    while (Char.IsDigit(line[i]))
                    {
                        number += line[i];
                        if (i == line.Length - 1) break;
                        i++;
                    }
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(number);
                    number = "";
                }
                i++;
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

Решение лобовое и выглядит не очень, существует ли более грамотное?

Comment: Строка на входе как выглядит?

Comment: Метод нужно реализовать для любой строки

Comment: ваш код не сработает для любой строки.

Comment: А для какой конкретно ?

Comment: так я и спрашиваю, какие строки вы обрабатываете?

Comment: Я попросил привести пример строки

Comment: Не тратье мое время, приведите ваш формат строки на входе. Как приведете, можете меня позвать, я перечитаю вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, вот строка : "dsa@#!%$#%%&^%*&^()5sadd2"

Comment: Какой результат вы из этой строки ожидаете? 7? Что насчет строк `---5----5++++5---` или `1e10-1.098`?

Comment: Что насчет `99999999999999999999999999999999` ?

Comment: dsa@#!%$#%%&^%*&^()5sadd2, результат 7
---5----5++++5---, результат -5
1e10-1.098, результат 108

Comment: `static int SumNumbersInLine(string line) => Regex.Matches(line, @"[-]?\d+").Select(x => x.Value).Select(int.Parse).Sum();` ?